# Agricola Family Growth by 2 (or more)

Tags: agricola

Is it legal to use the Family Growth action to extend your family by 2 or even 3 if you have enough rooms? The rules do not forbid it, but they only talk in singular about the new family member.

Answer (score 14):

You can add at most one newborn regardless of the number of empty rooms you might have.

[The rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Agricola_ENG.pdf) are clear on this:

> After Family Growth, also 1 Minor Improvement (Stage 2): A player may only use this Family growth space if he has more empty rooms than Family members.
>
> A player who chooses a Family growth action adds their newborn offspring to the Action space
> In the Return home phase, the new Family **member** is taken home ...  A Player who takes the Family growth action will therefore have **one** additional (adult) Family
> member to use from the following round onwards.

Answer (score 6):

Each 'Family Growth' action gets you one additional person.  You can do more than one 'Family Growth' action in a turn (getting multiple people) if the spaces are available.